# bun is installed, but its commands don't working

Tags: javascript, command, bun

When I trying to create a project or run a file or any command, nothing happens. just `--version` is working :(

[image]

How to fix this

Comment: Have you tried `bun http.js`?

Comment: Post actual code, not images.

Comment: @Palladium02 yes

Comment: @Aidin53 That is interesting as both `bun http.js` and `bun run http.js` should work. What is the general setup (OS)?

Comment: @Palladium02 windows10 with ubuntu 22.04

Comment: It's impossible to unswear a question why the code that you didn't include when run with bun "doesn't work". You didn't even tell us what is in your program, for all we know it could be an infinite loop, or listening on some other port etc. How did you install bun? Does it work for a simple program with a single console.log? Or for any other programs that you wrote? Whaat is their source code? Do they work in Deno? In Node? Does really **only** --version work? Did you try bun init, bun install, bun add, bun link, etc.? You provided hardly any data so no wonder it's not answered for so long.

Answer (score 0):

"Nothing" happened for me as well, turns out it was running and just didn't log anything on successful start. Add a console log to your endpoint

```
Bun.serve({
  async fetch(req) {
    console.log(req);
  }
})
```

and run

```bash
curl -X GET localhost:3000
```